# How do I get the model instance inline with the main Eloquent query by foreign key reference

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, eloquent-relationship

My question is simple.

I have 2 tables. "Users" and "Access Levels".
The Access Levels table contains the names of the available levels on the site. Something like this:

Access Level Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | admin |
| 2 | subscriber |

And in the Users table, I'm using the access_level through foreign key. Something like this:

Users Table

| id | username | access_level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 1 |
| 2 | user2 | 2 |
| 3 | user3 | 2 |

Now I'm querying all the user in usercontroller with User:all(). The results return a collection which includes the access_level id as expected. But I want to include the name of the associated access_level within the same result set/collection. I've tried searching for Eloquent relationships, but I'm not able to understand the concept.

This is the result that I'm expecting:

```
Array(
      [id => 1,username => user1, access_level => admin],
      [id => 2,username => user2, access_level => subscriber],
      [id => 3,username => user3, access_level => subscriber],
)
```

**EDIT**

After applying the code as suggested by @xenooo, I see that it returns the results with a "relations" key which has the foreign_key model instance. I've done your implementation on another set of tables. This time, in place of users, its books. And category in place of access_level. This is the response that I get with `dd()`. I've used the following code,

```
$books = Book::with('category')->find(1);
dd($books);
```

[dd of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At9aK.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you must define the relationship of your database to your model. Assuming that you have a model for `AccessLevel` :

```
// app/Models/AccessLevel.php

public function users() : HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'access_level');
}
```

```
// app/Models/User.php

public function accessLevel() : BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AccessLevel::class,'access_level');
}
```

To include the relationship when querying.

```
User::with('accessLevel')->get(); // accessLevel is the name of the function you define.
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But it still doesn't return the model object. When I try to access the name of level with $user->access_level->name, it still doesn't work. $user->access_level is returning 'int'

Comment: Can you show me how you did it ?

Comment: The same way that you've shown. $user->access_level returns just a single value instead of a model instance

Comment: Can you add the result of your query if you put it inside a `dd()`